# Need equality of CPBarPlot.barOffset in CPScatterPlot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

What is equality of `CPBarPlot.barOffset` in `CPScatterPlot` ? So I can change the offset of my scatter plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `barOffset` is a CGFloat. It is the amount that the bars are offset from their true position given by the `location` coordinate. The units are a fraction of the `barWidth` property. For example:

```
barOffset = 0.5;   // moves the bars half a barWidth in the positive direction
barOffset = -0.25; // moves the bar a quarter of a barWidth in the negative direction
```

Comment: Eric... i dont know if this answers the question. I have the same doubt as deden and there seems to be no property called as "barOffset" on CPTScatterPlot class... Can you please elaborate a bit on this answer..